# Authorize.net PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getSubscriptionDetailType() on array

Tags: php, arrays, oop, authorize.net

I'm creating Authorize.net Recurring billing report and i get list of subscriptions array.

```
$subscriptions[] = $response->getSubscriptionDetails();
```

when i try to echo values inside array like below, i get this error 
"PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getSubscriptionDetailType() on array"

```
echo $subscriptions[0]->getSubscriptionDetailType()->id;
```

i tried to var_dump and see what's going on inside this array..  i got this result

```html
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(net\authorize\api\contract\v1\SubscriptionDetailType)#200 (16) {
      ["id":"net\authorize\api\contract\v1\SubscriptionDetailType":private]=>
      int(4362259)
      ["name":"net\authorize\api\contract\v1\SubscriptionDetailType":private]=>
      string(29) "MetroCare Dental Subscription"
      ["status":"net\authorize\api\contract\v1\SubscriptionDetailType":private]=>
      string(7) "expired"
      ["createTimeStampUTC":"net\authorize\api\contract\v1\SubscriptionDetailType":private]=>
      object(DateTime)#195 (3) {
        ["date"]=>
        string(26) "2017-02-06 17:02:50.287000"
        ["timezone_type"]=>
        int(3)
        ["timezone"]=>
        string(3) "UTC"
      }
      ["firstName":"net\authorize\api\contract\v1\SubscriptionDetailType":private]=>
      string(5) "javed"
      ["lastName":"net\authorize\api\contract\v1\SubscriptionDetailType":private]=>
      string(5) "Malik"
      ["totalOccurrences":"net\authorize\api\contract\v1\SubscriptionDetailType":private]=>
      int(1)
      ["pastOccurrences":"net\authorize\api\contract\v1\SubscriptionDetailType":private]=>
      int(1)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The var dump shows the subscription details-object is in an array inside another array. Both arrays contain one element (with offset 0), so it would be:

```
$response[0][0]->getSubscriptionDetails();
```

Comment: ahh, yes.. i was really frustrated and did not noticed... it works, Thanks mate